# Magento - Users unable to login from corporate networks with Bluecoat / F5 Load balancers

Tags: networking, load-balancing, login, magento

Hoping someone has come across this issue before with Magento and corporate clients.

We have two clients for our Magento site who both have their internal networks setup using bluecoat security devices and F5 load balancers. Some users within these networks are unable to login to Magento - Magento eventually is sending a 302 redirect to /index.php/ when users attempt to log in.

Through our testing, the problem appears to be isolated to this setup - we can log into the accounts in question from anywhere outside of these networks without issue, and if the client tries to access the site without going through the F5 load balancer, they are able to log in successfully.

Strangely enough, the issue only started occurring for the two sites the day after we introduced a system upgrade which added a new site to the Magento installation. The system upgrade should not have affected any standard login functionality, and as said, the problem does not appear to be with the users in question, but with where the users are accessing the site from.

Initially we thought the issue might have something to do with communications between the client's networks and the network which the server was hosted on, so we've tried moving the server to different hosts, but this has not helped.

I'm currently waiting for more info from the clients on exact devices / models used in their network setup. I will update this post if more information becomes avaliable.

Magento version is enterprise edition of ver. 1.9.0.0

Does anyone know of any tucked away Magento settings that might be able to cause this kind of behavior? Experience with this kind of set-up and ideas for things to look at?

All help and ideas for things to follow-up would be appreciated - as this is a current production issue for a large number of users. I will respond asap with any requests for additional information on the topic, but currently am not able to disclose any identifying information on the project in question, and/or the clients experiencing issues.

Thanks in advance for any assistance offered :)

Note: This question has also been posted on the Magento forums: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/277917/
And also on Stack overflow (Moved here as a commenter thought this site may be better suited):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133978/magento-users-unable-to-login-from-corporate-networks-with-bluecoat-f5-load

Comment: Are you using HTTPS for customer accounts?

Comment: Also, are you using JS combine? I've seen both HTTPS and JS combine present odd issues with some firewalls...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you've isolated the issue to the F5.  Which model of F5 device are you running and which modules are you running on top of it?  For example, ASM is F5's Web App Firewall and if it's enabled, it could cause apps to stop functioning.

Also, F5 LTM has the ability to implement something called iRules.  Basically, it's TCL-based scripting language to implement logic in the traffic flow.  Perhaps there's logic implemented in an iRule (or general config of the virtual server) that's causing users' login attempts to fail.

One thing you can try is to create a new forwarding or performance virtual server to further segregate any potential issues with an existing configuration element with the existing virtual server.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you may need to configure [persistence](https://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/products/big-ip_ltm/manuals/product/ltm_implementation/sol_http_lb_cookie.html). What can happen in this situation is that you will login to back end server A) and then on future requests end up connected to server B). You never logged into server B) and you get redirected back to the login page. This clobbers the login data in the local browser for server A) when you log in to server B) and then it seems like you are never logged in because you have to log in to A) again when you get load balanced back there.

Otherwise, you are probably using a more exotic authentication method (client SSL certificates, Kerberos, NTLM, etc) and need to provide more details.